# YA Submitting Multiple Forms with AJAX Post

Tags: ajax

I searched high & low, found a ton of near hits, and yet still searching for an answer.

Consider basic scenario:

```
<form id="id1"  onsubmit="return submit_add2cart();" >


<script>
function submit_add2cart() {
$.ajax
({
type:'POST',
url: 'ajax.pl',
data:$('id1').serialize(),
success: function(response) {
alert(response);
}}
);
return false;
}
</script>
```

Now, let's say I have multiple forms on same page that want to call same submit_add2cart() function; submit_add2cart() **should only process calling form.**

```
<form id="id1"  onsubmit="return submit_add2cart();" >
<form id="id2"  onsubmit="return submit_add2cart();" >
<form id="id3"  onsubmit="return submit_add2cart();" >
```

What would the code look like for submit_add2cart()?

Thank you,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `form`s with `action` attribute, which is compulsory and add a class, say `ajax-submit`:

```
<form id="id1" action="ajax.pl" class="ajax-submit">
<form id="id2" action="ajax.pl" class="ajax-submit">
<form id="id3" action="ajax.pl" class="ajax-submit">
```

Now, using jQuery's unobtrusive method to bind the submit action:

```
$(function () {
  $(".ajax-submit").submit(function () {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
      alert(response);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

You don't need a separate function, or three different methods for it. Only the form that gets submitted will be submitted along its own data and not others'.

Comment: Fantastic, exactly the solution I was looking for, many thanks!

Comment: If I may push my luck a bit further :-)  So I have 2 submit buttons on this form:  <type="submit" name"add2cart"> and <type="submit" name="add2wish">.  Basically add to cart or to wish list. In my original CGI way of submitting form I was able to determine which button was clicked by looking for "add2wish" in parameters list - if there, then add2wish was pressed.   It now seems with AJAX pressed submit button name no longer figures in parameter list... is this right? How, then, can I differentiate  between the two? Thank you in advance, Michael

Comment: Sure... @Plavnostruev Would you mind accepting my answer, while I seek a solution to your issue?